# If player comes within a radius of enemy,change state

Tags: python, pygame

So I've been teaching myself some `pygame` for the past few months, doing a spaceship game.

I have multiple enemy spaceships that guard a certain area. If the player comes within a certain radius of them, I want to change the enemy's state. What's the best way to do this for a beginner, without using vectors?

Comment: Calculate the distance between them at each tick, do something if the distance falls below a certain value...?

Comment: ok,what do you mean by tick?

Comment: I mean each time around your main game loop, when you probably call [`clock.tick()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick)

Comment: I'm assuming a simple 2D game where you could just simply "draw" a circle (or square, whatever) around your enemy and then on the game loop you would check if your player collide with that invisible figure. The second answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312781/pygame-collision pretty much should give you and idea of how to do the collision detection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method in your program called `is_close` and then call it for each `player and enemy` comparison. It would look something like this:

```
def is_close(object1, object2, distance):
    return math.hypot(object2.x-object1.x, object2.y-object1.y) < float(distance)

... #rest of your code

while True:  #This is your main while loop
    ... #rest of your code

    for enemy in enemies:
        if is_close(player, enemy, 25):
            enemy.state = new_state  #change state, this may simply be a color change
```

Comment: using `return True if some_condition else False` is superfluous, just use `return some_condition`. Also, to get the euclidean distance between two points, just use the built-in `math.hypot` function; no need to re-create such a function yourself. So `is_close` could be simplified to `return math.hypot(object2.x-object1.x, object2.y-object1.y) < float(distance)`

Comment: @DominicKexel, Thank you for that simplification. I have updated the answer accordingly.