# How to add a collision when the player touches the baby

Tags: python, pygame

I have a game and I want the game to add one point when the player touches the baby. I know how to add the score but I don't know how to make the system understand that there was a collision between them.

This is the main part of my code:

```
while Level1:
    thing_rect = pygame.Rect(random.randrange(display_width), -60, 40, 40)
    thing_speed = 2
    while lives == 3:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return
        # adds the images and movement        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_Pl = x_Pl - 40
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_Pl = x_Pl + 40
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_Pl = x_Pl + 0
    gameDisplay.blit(Level1_Back, (0,0) )
    smallText_2 = pygame.font.Font("LSANS.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Use the arrow keys to move", smallText_2, black)
    textRect.center = ( (730+(180/2)), (200+(50/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
    gameDisplay.blit(lives_3, (10, 10) )
    gameDisplay.blit(Character_1, (x_Pl, 275))
    thing_rect.y += thing_speed
    if thing_rect.y > display_height:
        thing_rect.y = 0 - thing_rect.height
        thing_rect.x = random.randrange(display_width)

    gameDisplay.blit(Baby_1, thing_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you for all the help.
(If you need more of the code just tell me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyGame Collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312781/pygame-collision)

Comment: there are several other SO-posts if you search for `pygame collision` - did you look them up and they were not adequate?

Comment: Are you using `pygame.sprite.Sprite` for your baby? (Don't quite understand the game, but I'd recommend looking into this if you aren't)

Comment: I didn't see the python collision post and no, I'm not using sprite. But I may have figured out an easier option and if it doesn't work then I will check the post. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need an if statement something like this:
`if thing_rectX and thing_rectY >= Baby_1X and baby_1Y:
    touch_baby(paramaters)`
Obviously you would have to make a function called touch_baby and some variables which store the X and Y positions of the baby and the thing_rect but that is pretty much it. I hope this answered your question. :)

Comment: I have already figured it out and I used the same method as you.

Comment: Ok thats fine but if you have any more questions about what your making just email me at jmobey10@gmail.com. :-)